# If a Hilbert space-valued mapping is norm-decreasing, can we make sense of the limit of sums consisting of projected-values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be some separable Hilbert space with a given orthonormal basis $\{ e_n \}$. Write the projection onto the subspace spanned by first $N$ basis elements to be $P_N$.\

Now,let $g(t) : [0,1] \to H$ be some $H$-valued mapping that is decreasing in the norm:
\begin{equation}
\lVert g(t_2) \rVert \leq \lVert g(t_1) \rVert
\end{equation}
if $0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq 1$.

Then, for any monotone-increasing sequence $\{t_n \} \subset [0,1]$, it is clear that
\begin{equation}
0 \leq \sum_{i=1,3,5, \cdots } \Bigl( \lVert g(t_i) \rVert^2 - \rVert g(t_{i+1}) \rVert^2 \Bigr) \leq \lVert g(0) \rVert^2 - \lVert g(1) \rVert^2 <\infty
\end{equation}

However, I am stuck at the case where $P_N$ is acting:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1,3,5, \cdots } \Bigl( \lVert [P_N g](t_i) \rVert^2 - \rVert [P_Ng](t_{i+1}) \rVert^2 \Bigr) 
\end{equation}

I am not even sure if the series converges for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, what will be the limit of this series as $N \to \infty$?

These issues seem totally nontrivial and very frustrating to tackle... Could anyone please help me prove or find any counterexample..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series in question does not converge in general.

Indeed, let $N=1$. For $t\in[0,1]$, let $g(t):=e_1$ if $t$ is rational and $g(t):=e_2$ if $t$ is irrational. Then $g$ is decreasing in the norm.

Let $(t_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $[0,1]$ such that $t_i$ is rational iff $i$ is odd. Then
\begin{equation}
s_N:=\sum_{i=1,3,5, \cdots } \Big( \|[P_N g](t_i)\|^2 -\| [P_Ng](t_{i+1})\|^2 \Big) \\
=\sum_{i=1,3,5, \cdots } \Big( \|e_1\|^2 -\|0\|^2 \Big) =\infty.
\end{equation}

---

The OP asked in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455729/if-a-hilbert-space-valued-mapping-is-norm-decreasing-can-we-make-sense-of-the-l/455730#comment1179939_455730): "How abou $N$ going to infinity?" Let us modify the above example to have $s_N=\infty$ for all natural $N$, so that $s_N\to\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

To do so, for $t\in[0,1]$ let $g(t):=e_n$ if $t=1-\frac1{2n}$ for some natural $n$ and $g(t):=e_1$ otherwise. Then $g$ is decreasing in the norm.

Let $t_j:=1-\frac1j$, so that $(t_j)$ is a strictly increasing sequence in $[0,1]$. Then for each natural $N$
\begin{equation}
s_N=\sum_{i=1,3,5, \cdots } \Big( \|[P_N g](t_i)\|^2 -\| [P_Ng](t_{i+1})\|^2 \Big) \\
=\sum_{n=1,2,\ldots} \Big( \|[P_N g](t_{2n-1})\|^2 -\| [P_Ng](t_{2n})\|^2 \Big)  
\\
=\sum_{n=N+1,N+2,\ldots} (1-0)=\infty. \quad\Box
\end{equation}

Comment: I see. How abou $N$ going to infinity? Can we recover the original series?

Comment: @Isaac : I have added details on that as well.